# Why does my WPF UI lag when streaming lots of IP camera's in a single instance, but not when running the same amount of streams in multiple instances?

Tags: c#, wpf, video-streaming, ip-camera

We have created a WPF application which allows you to livestream multiple IP cameras(Mobotix). This application works fine when connecting it with a few streams. All streams are rendered correctly and without any delay.

However when we try to run the application with more than 20 livestreams, we experience problems with some steams no longer updating and the UI of the WPF application lagging.

We can fix this issue by turning down the quality and/or size of the livestreams. But unfortunately  this is not acceptable as the images do not contain enough detail.

After a lot of debugging, and trying with different ways to display the steams, to no avail, we noticed that if we run multiple instances of same application each rendering a limited amount of steams (for example 3 instances with 8 livestreams each), that there are no issues with any of the instances nor the camera streams themselves.

With this information we were wondering why there is a difference with one instance of the application running 24 streams or 3 instances of the same application running 8 streams each.

Does anyone here know what causes this behavior? Is there some sort of memory limitation for each application instance? Or a limitation of some kind in the GUI thread of a WPF application? Maybe there are other things we are failing to see here?

Any help would be highly appreciated!

Comment: I used to have this problem with an old version of Omnicast and simply had to open multiple instances. Just curious, how are you handling the streams? Are they being decoded directly from the camera streams or are they being processed by a server first? What kind of encoding are you using? And what kind of container are the streams sitting in within the UI?